# Loading Razor views from a database - VirtualPathProvider and CacheDependency confusion

Tags: sql-server-2005, asp.net-mvc-3, view, razor

I'm confused as to how `CacheDependency` works in `VirtualPathProvider.GetCacheDependency()`.

Every example I've seen creates a cache dependency based on some physical file on disk, while I'm returning records from a database. Right now, I'm overriding `GetFileHash` and just returning the last date/time the relevant record was modified as the hash string. This works well, and I'm not sure using a `CacheDependency` item would affect the performance as I'd still have to go check the database every time the view is requested to see if it's been updated, but I'm still curious how to use `CacheDependency.`

Has anyone used this when returning views from a database?

**Update**

Using this now (http://razorengine.codeplex.com/) which works VERY well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point of `CacheDependency` is to provide you with an event that will be called when the cache becomes invalid (because the file on disk changed). Check out [SqlCacheDependency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.sqlcachedependency.aspx) that does the same thing with SQL Server entries.